# Update and add data in sql from multiple excel files

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, vba

Let's say I have the following sheet on an excel file:

```
KEY   | ID | Account | Value
01002 | 01 | 002     | 10
```

As you can see, "KEY" is result of combining "ID" and "Account"

Now, I know how to import a table into an SQL form. I also know how to replace it. But I'm having trouble to **add and update** SQL table from an excel file.

For example,

If after adding this to an SQL table:

```
KEY   | ID | Account | Value
01003 | 01 | 003     | 10
02008 | 02 | 008     | 11
```

I then update this :

```
 KEY   | ID | Account | Value
 01003 | 01 | 003     | 14
 02009 | 02 | 009     | 10
```

key 01003 will be updated with the new value, while key 02009 will be added as a new entry. key 02008 will stay as it is.

Is there any way to do this?

If so, is there any way to run this on multiple workbooks (let's say, multiple workbooks in a folder)

I'm fine with VBA (excel add-in)

One way I could think about the latter one is using the same macro that was used to merge several workbooks into one, but replacing the query to update the excel file with whatever query that can do the above thing (update or add)

Comment: Import your raw data to a staging table.   Manipulate as required.  Write to your main table from the staging table.

Comment: Please explain the logic of the update as you can also calculation prior to import.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking out Sequel pro. It has a great import function that walks you through everything. As well as set the delimiters nice and easy!

I believe it will solve your key issue.

If you need help further comment and ill help you as much as I can

http://www.sequelpro.com/